# Change permalinks for posts but not custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, permalinks

I want my permalink for my standard posts to be www.mywebsite.com/photoblog/name-of-post

So I've written the custom structure as: /photoblog/%postname%/

However, my custom post type 'projects' permalinks now displays as www.mywebsite.com/projects/photoblog/name-of-post

How can I fix this so it only displays 'photoblog' in the standard post type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added with_front='false' to the slug rewrite for the custom post type

Answer (score 0):

You could add a category called photoblog into you blog and put all the post in there and then leave the custom structure as category/name-of-post.